# HTTP Get response in Typescript to get data from google spreadsheets

Tags: typescript, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a project in `Node JS` and `Typecript` in which I am working with `google spreadsheets`.

Now I am getting the data from the google API at the following `URL`: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get I add in the fileId field the ID of the spreadsheet, in the supportsAllDrives field true and in the fields (id, name, modifiedTime)

The HTTP response is as follows:
GET [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%7BfileId%7D)

What I want is to form this HTTP response in TypeScript with the properties that I am adding in the URL (fileID and supportsAllDrives?

**My problem**: how can I form the HTTP response in Typescript code with fileID and supportsAllDrives properties?

Comment: POST request does not put parameters to url but data object to body. I think there are many examples in the documentation.

Comment: @idfurw From the URL of the API that I have put I have no problem doing it. My question is, how can I do it from the Typescript code?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve; can you please provide more details? So basically you just want to make the request in TypeScript?

Comment: @ale13 I want to form the URL that the API provides: GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[fileId}. With the supportsAllDrives and fields properties, with the data that I show in the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be an answer ... Here you have a function which produces a json object from a spreadsheet. You can include in typescript.

```
function getJson(id,gid){
  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=${gid}`).getContentText();
  var jsonString = txt.match(/(?<="table":).*(?=}\);)/g)[0]
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  return(json)
}
```

- with id of the spreadsheet and gid of your sheet (may be 0)
- note that first row is dedicated to labels, then rows[0] corresponds to row#2 and c[0] corresponds to column A
- if you want to retrieve B1 (column 2 row 1) : `json.cols[1].label`
- if you want to retrieve B2 (column 2 row 2) : `json.rows[0].c[1].v`

Comment: This is fine, but I want to use the google api to retrieve the information. What I want to know first is how to add the supportsAllDrives and fields properties to the URL https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[fileId} as I put in the question

Answer (score 0):

or this one, more suited to the html page

```
<script>

function reqListener () {
  var jsonString = this.responseText.match(/(?<="table":).*(?=}\);)/g)[0];
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  return json
}

var id = '______your_id_______';
var gid = '____your_grid_id___';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", url, true);
oReq.send();
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The request you want to make will look like this:

- HTTP

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID?supportsAllDrives=true&fields=id%2C%20name%2C%20modifiedTime&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

- TypeScript

```
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
drive.files.get{
    fields: 'files(id, name, modifiedTime)',
    supportsAllDrives: true
}
```

#### Reference

- [Drive API files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get).